# Finding the general Taylor polynomial formula for $f(x)=\log\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)$

Tags: calculus, polynomials, taylor-expansion

I am trying to find the general form of the Taylor polynomial for $f(x)=\log\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)$.

The $log$ is of base $e$ and I have rewritten the original formula as: $\log(1+x)-\log(1-x)$ for my calculations. I have calculated the derivatives up to $5$:

$$\begin{align}
f^{(1)}(x)&=\frac{1}{x+1} - \frac{1}{x-1}\\
f^{(2)}(x)&= \frac{1}{(x-1)^{2}} - \frac{1}{(x+1)^{2}}\\
f^{(3)}(x)&=\frac{2}{(x+1)^{3}} - \frac{2}{(x-1)^{3}}\\
f^{(4)}(x)&=\frac{6}{(x-1)^{4}} - \frac{6}{(x+1)^{4}}\\
f^{(5)}(x)&=\frac{24}{(x+1)^{5}} - \frac{24}{(x-1)^{5}}\\
\end{align}$$

Based on the formula for computing Taylor polynomials:

$P_{n}(x)=f(a)+\frac{f^{1} (a)}{1!}(x-a)+\frac{f^{2} (a)}{2!}(x-a)^{2}+...
+\frac{f^{n} (a)}{n!}(x-a)^{n}$

I have computed, up to the 5th derivative, the Taylor polynomial for $\log(1+x)-\log(1-x)$

$=  2x+\frac{2x^{3}}{3}+\frac{2x^{5}}{5}+...+$[general nth term of Taylor polynomial]

I cannot figure out the general form of the Taylor polynomial. If someone could please explain this to me so I can better understand how to derive this and learn from their complete answer, it would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Start with the taylor series of $\log(1+x)$, if you find a general term then you can substitute $x\leftarrow -x$ and sum term by term.

Answer (score 1):

Use geometric series for this.  For $|x|<1$, by integration.
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n =\frac1{1-x} \implies \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}=-\ln(1-x)+C$$

Setting $x=0$, shows that $C=0$.

So,
$$-\ln(1-x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n}.$$
Again for $|x|<1$,
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^nx^n=\frac1{1+x}\implies\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{n+1}}{n+1}=\ln(1+x)+C.$$

Again, setting $x=0$ shows, $C=0$.
So,
$$\ln(x+1)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}x^n}n.$$

This gives 
$$\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)=\ln(1+x)-\ln(1-x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(1+(-1)^{n-1})x^n}n.$$
Note that
$$1+(-1)^{n-1}=\begin{cases}2, & n\text{ odd}\\0, & n\text{ even}.\end{cases}$$

So, we finally get
$$\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)=2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you possibly help me with the second calculation and combine those two derivations to form a complete nth term general polynomial? I am really struggling forming the final general term.

Comment: I'll expand my answer.